# how can I use webkit-line-clamp?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

I have this code for making my paragraph short

```css
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

but the problem is that this code makes everything in one-line. I want to go with 3 lines of text then...
I searched in the Google about it and I find out we have a WebKit for it

```css
webkit-line-clamp
```

but I have no idea how to use it and it doesn't work...

Comment: Hi! Please add some code snippet showing your exact problem.

Comment: line clamp isn't supported by every browser.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul Hi buddy .. please read my question again :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "not work"? How did webkit-line-clamp not work?

Answer (score 7):

### Method - 1 : Using `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

```css
span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 250px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span>
```

### Method - 2 : Using `-webkit-line-clamp`

```css
p {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical; 
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Comment: Hello friend, thank you for your help.
I do not want to show after three lines(...)

Comment: Check now @nafashmn.ir I updated answer. Have two methods.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution without flexbox**

Set height of text container and use webkit-line-clamp accordingly.

```
.line-clamp-3 {
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Text will be shown like this.
[image]

**Solution with flexbox**

You can also take help from this link: https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
}

.short-and-fixed {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.long-and-truncated {
  margin: 0 20px;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}

.long-and-truncated span {
  display: inline;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-child short-and-fixed">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child long-and-truncated">
    <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child short-and-fixed">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello friend, thank you for your help.
Using this code solves my problem but does not leave three dots at the end of the line(...)

Comment: Please use -webkit-line-clamp and height respectively to show three dots(...). can you share the text div container?