# How to make a wrapping label that eventually elides in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

How can I make a label of a certain width that wraps until it fills a max-height, and then elides?

For example:

```
 _________________________
| This label has a lot of |
| text that can wrap up   |
| to a certain height and |
| then it will eventua... |
 -------------------------
```

And if the text is short enough to not fill the max-height:

```
 _________________________
| This text doesn't need  |
| to elide.               |
 -------------------------
```

Comment: Do you want something like [line-clamp](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/)  ? Or do you want the text to scroll up like a [marquee](https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/kQebQO)

Comment: Oh, wow, I'd never heard of line-clamp. I think that's what I want but I need to play around with it. Looks like every browser supports it too. Cool!

Comment: No problem, there's some answers on this already [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63376172/how-can-i-use-webkit-line-clamp), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76853983/have-content-display-after-line-clamp/76854311), so it may be a duplicate

Comment: Ok but that requires you to look up line-clamp lol - I didn't even know about it and never found it in my searching around this issue...so hopefully this question will help someone. Post line-clamp as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: Also, is there any way to make the line number setting be a variable that I can input from html? As far as I know you cannot do that. I'm using Angular and SASS just FYI.

Comment: Oh you can use `-webkit-line-clamp: var(--lines)` in the css and then `style="--lines: 4"` in the html.